# Jersey client filter thread safety

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey, http-authentication

I am using a singleton instance of the jersey client configured through spring, with multiple threads that each set different authentication filters on the client. According to the docs

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.3/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.html.

setting filters is not guaranteed to be thread safe, which means thread A is not guaranteed to be authenticated as itself when other threads set filters simultaneously.

Is there a work around to this issue, other than creating a new client for each thread? I would like to avoid this as it is an expensive operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you will be able to use a single client safely with multiple threads in this manner. I would suggest creating a pool of clients, and have each thread borrow a client from the pool, set the appropriate authentication filter, and then clear the filter before returning the client to the pool.

Apache commons has a [pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) component that would work well for this.

Comment: Excellent suggestion - thank you. 
I will try using [Spring AOP API for object pooling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/aop-api.html#aop-ts-pool), which in turn uses Apache commons pool under the hood.